# Please Help changing Base URL from / to /public

Tags: asp-classic

I have migrated a classic ASP web site from my local machine that has references (not absolute to my knowledge but virtual and relative) to the root of /

I am trying to run it on a hosted site that insists the files be located in /public as the root.

I have read several posts but just don't understand if this can be done easily in htaccess  or not

But can't seem to quite get it right.

Can any one help?

---

I have tried this rewrite rule:

```
DirectoryIndex default asp

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

and I have tried playing with rewrite base:
    DirectoryIndex default asp

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /default asp
```

---

An example calls that don't resolve are as follows:

The 404 redirect seems to work on links to link to correct default.asp - but - in / instead of /public/default.asp 
The logo itself can't be found because it is looking for it in 
   /logos/poolowners/
instead of
   /public/logos/poolowners/

Is there way to do this without having to host this on a different provider that allows me to put the site files directly in the root / instead of /public?

Thanks,
  Carl

Answer (score 0):

I believe .htaccess is a linux only file.

However, you could edit your web.config to redirect to there on 404...

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="/public"
                    mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="404"
                redirect="/"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Source:[Web.config custom errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Edit: Another option would be to download Notepad++, open all documents and do a "find/replace all documents" for like Find:"/public" Replace"/" so you remove ALL /public's and then you never have to worry.